# Ola Hallengren Index maintenance on servers with Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, index-tuning, ola-hallengren

I'm configuring the Ola Hallengren scripts for Index maintenance on all servers in may Availability Group cluster which has several AG's and databases which are not in AG's.

If I select the "ALL_DATABASES" option, is the script intelligent enough to exclude the read only secondary replicas?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the script is intelligent enough.

This is explicitly stated in [the FAQ](https://ola.hallengren.com/frequently-asked-questions.html):

> **How should I configure IndexOptimize for an Availability Group?**
>
> Indexes can only be rebuilt or reorganized and statistics only updated
>   on the primary replica in an availability group. IndexOptimize has a
>   check for this.
>
> The jobs should be configured identically and be enabled and scheduled
>   on all the replicas.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had seen this comment but I could not decide if the configuration it was referring to was that I had to specify "Availability Groups" in the backup options or If I could still just specify "All databases".

Answer (score 4):

Yes it will only optimize the databases which it can optimize, it will not fail if the database is read-only or in any other non optimizable-able state

Comment: Just to clarify - he was asking about index maintenance, so you may wanna focus your answer on that. (Plus the backup answer gets a little bit trickier - you'd have to talk about backup preference, for example, so I'd steer clear of that in your answer.)

Comment: Thank you, Altered the answer guess I was not that awake this morning